# React js, how to use xml as your html design

Tags: reactjs

I have a header/footer created from a cms tool which generated an xml file.

My xml:
https://uhf.microsoft.com/en-US/shell/xml/MSIrelandsFuture?headerId=MSIrelandsFutureHeader&footerid=MSIrelandsFutureFooter

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export default function RegisterEntry() {
    const [xml, setXML] = useState('');

    axios.get('https://uhf.microsoft.com/en-US/shell/xml/MSIrelandsFuture?headerId=MSIrelandsFutureHeader&footerid=MSIrelandsFutureFooter', {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Your xml file as string', response.data);
            setXML(response.data)
        });




    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {xml}
        </React.Fragment >
    )
}
```

Somehow these return the text of my xml, i'm not sure how to return the actual ui design

returns:
[image]

The result I wanted:

[image]

Comment: This may help https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-display-xml-data-using-reactjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DOMParser](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-joyrzp) to parse XML or HTML source code from a string into a DOM Document. The get the desired node and append it to some part of your document:

```
const appendToNode = (node, content) => {
    node.innerHTML += content;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const DOMParse = new DOMParser();
    let xmlDoc;
    axios
      .get(
        'https://uhf.microsoft.com/en-US/shell/xml/MSIrelandsFuture?headerId=MSIrelandsFutureHeader&footerid=MSIrelandsFutureFooter',
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        xmlDoc = DOMParse.parseFromString(response.data, 'text/xml');
        appendToNode(
          ref.current //--> some node in your document
          xmlDoc.querySelector('headerHtml').textContent //--> do the same with the rest of the nodes
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-joyrzp)

I recommend you to use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) library to transform the HTML string into a JSX element.

Comment: thank you for the help and providing an npm library. I have been searching since yesterday and most of the result from given where outdated and deprecated. These one works